# Meteor server asynchronous method calls and using the return results

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a method that does a really heavy computation on the server-sider, I need to call this method twice and use the result from these calls to do another computation:

```
combinationCalc: function(val1, val2) {
  var result1 = heavyCompute(val1);
  var result2 = heavyCompute(val2);

  return anotherComputation(result1, result2);
}
```

The value for result2 does not depend on value for result1, how can I execute these two computations asynchronously?

Comment: I'm interested in knowing the best design pattern for this in Meteor, and if there is any libraries that can keep my code nice and clean.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to share my own solution that I found through some research. This requires using NPM package fiber/future

```
Future = Meteor.npmRequire('fibers/future');

combinationCalc: function(val1, val2) {
  var fut1 = new Future();
  var fut2 = new Future();

  heavyCompute(val1, fut1);
  heavyCompute(val2, fut2);

  var result1 = fut1.wait();
  var result2 = fut2.wait();

  return anotherComputation(result1, result2);
}


heavyCompute(val, fut) {
  // ALL THE COMPUTES!
  fut.return(compute_result);
}
```

I wanted to have a single point of entry on the server, and as little confusing code as possible.

Comment: What makes the heavyCompute function non-blocking? Is there a `Meteor.defer` or something similar? As currently written, if you just throw computes in where it says "all the computes", seems like it would block.  Perhaps:

heavyCompute(val, fut) {
  Meteor.defer(function(){
     // ALL THE COMPUTES!
     fut.return(compute_result);
  });
}

Comment: Yes you are right, I think the original intent is to find a way such that

heavyCompute(val1, fut1);
heavyCompute(val2, fut2);

can run asynchronously, regardless of whether heavyCompute is blocking within itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Meteor methods](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods) which are called from the client and run asynchronously.

First declare the methods on the server:

```
Meteor.methods({
  firstMethod: function (arg) {
    this.unblock();
    //do stuff
  },
  secondMethod: function (arg) {
    this.unblock();
    //do stuff
  }
});
```

Note the use of `this.unblock();` which allows a method call from the client to be run without waiting for the previous call ([by default only one method can run at a time](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/method_unblock)).

Then, call the method from the client (you may also call them from the server):

```
Meteor.call('firstMethod', arg, function(error, result() {
  //do something with the result
});
Meteor.call('secondMethod', arg, function(error, result() {
  //do something with the result
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Meteor methods and session variables, you can asynchronously call meteor methods, save the results into session variables, and perform your second method call when both parameters are ready.

```
combinationCalc: function(val1, val2) {

  // Calls heavyCompute on val1
  Meteor.call('heavyCompute', val1, function(error, result) {
    Session.set('result1', result);
    // if heavyCompute on val2 finished first
    if(Session.get('result1') && Session.get('result2'))
      Meteor.call('anotherComputation', Session.get('result1'), Session.get('result2'), function(error, result) {
         Session.set('answer', result);
      });
  });

  // Calls heavyCompute on val2
  Meteor.call('heavyCompute', val2, function(error, result) {
    Session.set('result2', result);
    // if heavyCompute on val1 finished first
    if(Session.get('result1') && Session.get('result2'))
      Meteor.call('anotherComputation', Session.get('result1'), Session.get('result2'), function(error, result) {
         Session.set('answer', result);
      });
  });
}
```

Then, just call `Session.get('answer');` wherever you want to use the result.

To minimize redundant code, you can put checking for undefined inside the `anotherComputation` method itself.